# TinyMCE editor : How to change a tag path?

Tags: url, path, tinymce

after create link in TinyMCE editor with path : `/test/download.pdf`, TinyMCE  creating path like this:

```
../../../test/download.pdf
```

Is there a way to prevent this, so to TinyMCE dont add '../../../' in path ?

Thanks,

Pavle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TinyMCE has many URL handling options as documented here:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/url-handling/

Without seeing your code and TinyMCE configuration it is really impossible for anyone to tell you precisely why you are getting what you are getting.  Hopefully the options on that page will help you address the issue.